# Geopandas sjoin operations fail to capture only polygons within other as it excludes points on the boundary

Tags: python, geopandas

This is the code I'm using:
`result = geopandas.sjoin(tracts, city, how='inner', op=X)`
(where X is the operation I'm changing).

From the [documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#binary-predicates) these are some of the options for `op` and the results I've got:

- `covered_by`: "Returns True if every point of object is a point on the interior or boundary of other."
  [image: result of covered_by]
- `intersects`: "Returns True if the boundary or interior of the object intersect in any way with those of the other."
  [image: result of intersects]
- `overlaps`: "Returns True if the geometries have more than one but not all points in common"
  [image: result of overlaps]
- `within`: "Returns True if the object’s boundary and interior intersect only with the interior of the other"
  [image: result of within]

I need to get all of the tracts within the city (and only within the city, including the ones that touch the edges). From the documentation, I thought that `covered_by` would give me this, but apparently not. What `op` should I be using?

Comment: In cases likes this, where the smaller polygons **should** be fully within or fully outside of the bigger polygon, it is often handy to check the intersection between the larger polygon and the smaller polygon centroid

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @JGH.

This works:

```
tracts['centroid'] = tracts.centroid
tracts = tracts.set_geometry('centroid')
result = geopandas.sjoin(tracts, city, how='inner', op='within')
result = result .set_geometry('geometry')
```

[image: result using centroids and within]